# Interpolate point within a 3d triangle to a point within a 2d triangle

Tags: math, language-agnostic, 3d

Could someone give me the algorithm to solve this:

Given a 3D Triangle (p0, p1, p2) and a 3D point inside/on this triangle (px) and a 2D Triangle (p0', p1', p2'), the function will return a 2D point such that:

- if px == p0 then return p0'
- if px == p1 then return p1'
- if px == p2 then return p2'

and everything in between.

Comment: Challenge: make a *triangle* that *isn't* 2d...

Comment: "and everything in between": what does that mean?

Comment: if you express your point in barycentric coordinates, the rest should be trivial. Unless I don't get what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you want to project a 3D point to a 2D matrix, right?

There's many resources for that (check Wikipedia here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection) but this one http://www.flipcode.com/archives/Plotting_A_3D_Point_On_A_2D_Screen.shtml is a nice introduction!

Edit: also this recent article is a very understandable introduction http://creativejs.com/2012/01/day-12-3d-pixel-particles/

Answer (score 0):

I understand. Any point `px` on the plane of (`p0`,`p1`,`p2`) can represented by the [BaryCentric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system_%28mathematics%29) coordinates `a0`,`a1`,`a2` such that `px = a0*p0 + a1*p1 + a2*p2` in all coordinates. If you know the values for `a0`,`a1`,`a2` then you can apply them to (`p0'`,`p1'`,`p2'`) in order to find `px' = a0*p0' + a1*p1' + a2*p2'`.

To get the BaryCentric coordinates you need to solve a `3x3` system of linear equations

```
| px[0] |   | p0[0]  p1[0]  p2[0] | | a[0] |
| px[1] | = | p0[1]  p1[1]  p2[1] | | a[1] |
| px[2] |   | p0[2]  p1[2]  p2[1] | | a[2] |
```

In `C` the solution is

```
d = p0[0]*p1[1]*p2[2]-p0[0]*p1[2]*p2[1]-p0[1]*p1[0]*p2[2]+p0[1]*p1[2]*p2[0]+p0[2]*p1[0]*p2[1]-p0[2]*p1[1]*p2[0];
a0 = (p1[0]*p2[1]*px[2]-p1[0]*p2[2]*px[1]-p1[1]*p2[0]*px[2]+p1[1]*p2[2]*px[0]+p1[2]*p2[0]*px[1]-p1[2]*p2[1]*px[0])/d;
a1 = -(p0[0]*p2[1]*px[2]-p0[0]*p2[2]*px[1]-p0[1]*p2[0]*px[2]+p0[1]*p2[2]*px[0]+p0[2]*p2[0]*px[1]-p0[2]*p2[1]*px[0])/d;
a2 = (p0[0]*p1[1]*px[2]-p0[0]*p1[2]*px[1]-p0[1]*p1[0]*px[2]+p0[1]*p1[2]*px[0]+p0[2]*p1[0]*px[1]-p0[2]*p1[1]*px[0])/d;
```

With the coordinates for the 2D point as:

```
px'[0] = a0*p0'[0] + a1*p1'[0] + a2*p2'[0]
px'[1] = a0*p0'[1] + a1*p1'[1] + a2*p2'[1]
px'[2] = a0*p0'[2] + a1*p1'[2] + a2*p2'[2]
```